# csv to html table with multiple hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, csv, hyperlink

Was wondering is someone could assist me with this.

I am using this example [CSV to HTML Table](https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table)

I am trying to format an additional column as a hyperlink but honestly have no js skills would greatly appreciate any assistance. The example below shows the code for one column.

```js
 <script>

  //my custom function that creates a hyperlink
  function format_link(link){
    if (link)
      return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link + "</a>";
    else
      return "";
  }

  //initializing the table
  CsvToHtmlTable.init({
    csv_path: 'data/Health Clinics in Chicago.csv', 
    element: 'table-container', 
    allow_download: true,
    csv_options: {separator: ',', delimiter: '"'},
    datatables_options: {"paging": false},
    custom_formatting: [[4, format_link]] //execute the function on the 4th column of every row
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? are you getting an error when you run this code?

Comment: The code as is works perfectly. I am just asking for assistance with modifying it to format 2 columns in the csv as hyperlinks rather than 1 like in the in the example. Hope that helps. thanks for the reply.
My csv data has 2 fields with hyperlink data and I need to have the resulting table format them as such.

Comment: The documentation says to use an array of arrays, so it will probably be like this: custom_formatting: [[4, format_link], [6, format_link]]  - I've added an additional array to format a link in column 6

Comment: Thanks so much @LeoFarmer That resolved my issue!

Comment: @LeoFarmer - You should write up a simple example with an explanation so Ryan can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for csv-to-html-table states that:

> If you want to do custom formatting for one or more column, you can
>   pass in an array of arrays containing the index of the column and a
>   custom function for formatting it. You can pass in multiple formatters
>   and they will be executed in order.

In the example below, I demonstrate what an array of arrays for multiple links would look like. In my example column 4 and column 6 have links.

```
<script>

  //my custom function that creates a hyperlink
  function format_link(link){
    if (link)
      return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link + "</a>";
    else
      return "";
  }

  //initializing the table
  CsvToHtmlTable.init({
    csv_path: 'data/Health Clinics in Chicago.csv', 
    element: 'table-container', 
    allow_download: true,
    csv_options: {separator: ',', delimiter: '"'},
    datatables_options: {"paging": false},
    custom_formatting: [[4, format_link], [6, format_link]] //execute the function on the 4th column of every row
  });
</script>
```